# Not able to initialize context

Tags: java, spring

My application is throwing this error after starting the tomcat and unable to access the application.
I am using spring-Core-4.1.9_RELEASE and Spring Security-Core-4.0.3.RELEASE.

```
ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] [] [] [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - <Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: The use of "filters='none'" is no longer supported. Please define a separate <http> element for the pattern you want to exclude and use the attribute "security='none'".
```

Comment: Not a `spring` expert ... however, in your configuration file there is `"filters='none'"` entry,  which is no longer supported....

Answer (score 0):

This feature is deprecated. Spring versions newer than 3.0 will result in an runtime exception on startup.

Try to go for this instead:

```
<http pattern="/nonsecure/**" security="none"/>
```

In your case this should work:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" security="none" /> 
<intercept-url pattern="/framework/**" security="none"" /> 
<intercept-url pattern="/changePassword.htm" security="none" />
```

Comment: <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" filters="none" />
<intercept-url pattern="/framework/**" filters="none" />
<intercept-url pattern="/changePassword.htm" filters="none" />

Comment: how to make it in http tag

Comment: Just change `filters="none"` for `security="none"` in each `intercept-url` element

Comment: Changes didn't work. getting this error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 13; columnNumber: 58; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'security' is not allowed to appear in element 'intercept-url'.

Comment: Any suggestions ?